# Selecting only year from a given Date

Tags: sql, sorting, date

I have created a employee table with column as `Date_Of_Joining`.

I have entered the data in `YYYY-MM-DD` Format.

Now I want to retrieve the data of the employee only by using the `YEAR`.

For example if I have entered Date_Of_Joining as 2010-10-15, 2012-05-18 and 2008-04-16.

Now I want the details of the employee whose `Date_Of_Joining` is after 2010.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE YEAR(Date_Of_Joining) > 2010`. If `Date_Of_Joining` datatype is `DATE` the query will work, if the data type is varchar, then you need to convert it into `DATE` format then apply the query

Comment: In case if you want to filter with month and year, you can follow the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55845066/2451726)

Answer (score 1):

try do a query like this

```
select * from employee-table where year(Date_Of_Joining) > 2010
```

Replace "employee-table" with your table name.
This query will give all the data that is after year 2010

Comment: what if i want to get the data base on month and year only then ?

Comment: but what kind of filter do you want, specific year/month ?

Comment: I want the data base on Month and Year

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE YEAR(Date_Of_Joining) > 2010
```

If `Date_Of_Joining` datatype is `DATE` the query will work, if the data type is varchar, then you need to convert it into DATE format then apply the query.

In case if you want to filter with month and year, you can use as

```
 SELECT * FROM Employee
 WHERE YEAR(Date_Of_Joining) > 2010 AND MONTH(Date_Of_Joining) > 1
```

If the range between Jan 2010 and May 2013, you can use as

```
 SELECT * FROM Employee
 WHERE (YEAR(Date_Of_Joining) >= 2010 AND MONTH(Date_Of_Joining) >= 1) 
    OR (YEAR(Date_Of_Joining) <= 2013 AND MONTH(Date_Of_Joining) <= 5)
```

Comment: @Pankaj4U If it solves your problem, can you please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so that others know the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

just follow this

```
   SELECT  YEAR(Date_Of_Joining)
```

it is the general format to get year

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you phrase  this as:

```
Date_Of_Joining >= '2011-01-01'
```

That is, you should avoid using the expression `YEAR(Date_Of_Joining)`.  Why?  Using a function on a column prevents certain optimization strategies -- especially those using indexes and partitions.

For this particular example, you probably have a small amount of data, so it won't actually affect the performance of *this* query.  But you might as well learn how to write with performance in mind.